# Create a site collection app catalog using graph or sharepoint rest api token

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-rest-api

Site collection app catalog can be enabled using SharePoint Online Management Shell or Office365 CLI [as mentioned here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/site-collection-app-catalog#configure-and-manage-site-collection-app-catalogs).
is there any other way if I have Microsoft graph token or SharePoint rest api token with correct permission ?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

For graph api, there is only read endpoints for site resources in Microsoft graph API, we cannot create sites. Please check this documentation: [Working with SharePoint sites in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0)

For SharePoint rest api, we can only create modern sites collection. There is no ability to create site collection app catalog.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/site-creation-rest